# is it possible to write a function in vue 3 click event in template

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

The vue 3 button click not trigger in the google chrome extension, so now I want to put a simple function to the template to make sure the click event triggered or not. Is it possible to put the function in template in vue 3 like this:

```
<button type="button" class="translate-pop-button" @click="function() {alert('s')}">
        <span class="reddwarf-btn-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

I have tried to run but shows error:

```
content.js:17443 Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.alert is not a function
    at onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (content.js:17443:12)
    at callWithErrorHandling (content.js:7358:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (content.js:7367:21)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (content.js:15372:90)
```

what should I do to put a simple function into the click evnent?

Comment: Why not defining the function in the script part?

Comment: You can write functions but functions like "alert" are restricted. More here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#restricted-globals-access